# APK is downloaded as ZIP on some phones

Tags: android, mobile-website, vs-web-site-project

I'm facing an issue where in some android phones my .apk file is downloaded as .zip. I run a android game which can be downloaded from my website. I have created my website using wordpress Ocean WP theme with the help of elementor. What could be the reason for this. I tried modify the htaccess file in public.html folder but that's not working instead it stop access to my other website pages. Please let me know if any one knows the reason for this. Thanks

Comment: Please comment which modifications you did on .htaccess. Also I think APK files are like Zipped files, so it might be some issue with the file's mime type.

Comment: Please add some code. we need to look at what you did. Please show us the code of what you tried (example, both file versions, etc.). What resources are you using ? What are the phones that have an issue : HTC phone , samsung phone, is it because they have different download manager ? etc.

Comment: 1. At first I changed .htaccess name to .htaccess1 but that didn't help.Then I told users to download file in incognito mode and it helped and file was downloaded as .apk instead of .zip

Comment: 2. I used elementor and wordpress to create the website, I don't have any code knowledge to be very frank. The problem I'm facing when user download file via crome browser and mostly phones are redmi, 1+(Plus) and I think may be in that phones also which has android version 9 or above.

Comment: I want that whosoever download the file get downloaded in apk only and not as .zip and .txt